# Object.Equals en C#

Tags: c#

¿Es lo mismo utilizar el operador `==` que `Object.Equals` en C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

== es usada como una expresión de tipo object, va a resolver a System.Object.ReferenceEquals.

Equals es sólo un método virtual y se comporta como tal, por lo que se utilizará la versión anulada (que, para el tipo string compara el contenido)

respuesta  encontrada **[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals)**